# Apply frame on a sublayer after heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm creating a UITableViewCell which contain a image which fills the whole cell. i've created then created a sublayer on top of this image which is suppose to fill the whole image. However the issue is it isnt.

First i've set the height of the cell dynamic like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

    return (self.view.frame.height-40)/3;

}
```

Then i've set the layer like this in the cell subclass in awakeFromNib

```
    var imgOverlay: CALayer = CALayer()
    imgOverlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4).CGColor
    imgOverlay.frame = backgroundImage.bounds
    backgroundImage.layer.addSublayer(imgOverlay)
```

The result is this. here your can see that the layer does not cover the whole image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cell can be resized by UITableView many times during cell's lifecycle. In that case you need to reflect those changes by yourself. Override cell's `-setFrame` like this:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    self.imgOverlay.frame = self.bounds;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: You know how this would look like in swift?

Comment: Maybe like this: `override var frame : CGRect { didSet { self.imgOverlay.frame = self.bounds } } ?